# Hiding response from ExceptionHandlers in SpringDoc OpenApi

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, springdoc

I have Spring Boot MVC application where exceptions are handled within a general `@ControllerAdvice`. Some of them do not include a response body, like for instance:

```
@ExceptionHandler(EntityNotFoundException.class)
@ResponseStatus(NOT_FOUND)
void handleEntityNotFound() {
}
```

Everything works fine, but I run into issues if I want to expose my endpoints with [SpringDoc](https://springdoc.org). The exception handler is picked up correctly, however, the Swagger-UI displays a random response for `404`s:

[image: Wrong response schema]

Note, that this even isn't the response of the GET endpoint in question here, but a response from a method from a different `RestController`.

What do I have to do to hide wrong response? I already tried

```
  @ApiResponse(responseCode = "404", description = "Not found", content = @Content)
  @ExceptionHandler(EntityNotFoundException.class)
  @ResponseStatus(NOT_FOUND)
  void handleEntityNotFound() {
  }
```

as suggested in the docs, but that does not work.

Comment: I think I found the culprit: The response I'm getting for the `404` is from a different GET endpoint, which can return `application/json` or `text/event-stream` based on the `Accept` header of the request. This seems to trip up SpringDoc. :(

This seems like a bug in SpringDoc to me. I use `@Hidden` for the `text/event-stream` handler as a workaround for now, which is less than ideal.

Comment: Filed a bug report: https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/711

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: Have you tried replacing the `@ResponseStatus` annotation with `response.status = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND`  and adding a simple `@ApiResponse` with just `description`?   You would need the handler method signature with the `HttpServletResponse` argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is resolved in v1.4.1:

- https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/711

Comment: Nice: This is the bug report I filed. The guy closed the issue immediately telling me that my example is nonsense, only to edit his comment a few days later saying that now there's a fix. LOL.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to hide it and want to show the appropriate response, one way to do that is you can define a string as an example

```
public static final String exampleInternalError = "{\r\n"
            + "  \"code\": 404,\r\n"
            + "  \"message\": \"Resource not found\"\r\n" + "}";
```

same is used to show the example as

```
@ApiResponse(responseCode = "404",
                            description = "Resource not found",
                            //And different example for this error
                            content = @Content(schema = @Schema(implementation = ErrorResponse.class), 
                                   examples = @ExampleObject(description = "Internal Error", value = exampleInternalError)))
```